# Tapestry List of fields in a form to a List

Tags: tapestry

is it possible to create a form in tapestry that has multiple input fields with the same id and type that are stored as list in the class?
Something like the following.

sample.tml

```html
<t:form>
    <input t:type="upload" t:id="files" t:value="files" t:validate="required"/>
    <input t:type="upload" t:id="files" t:value="files" t:validate="required"/>
    <input t:type="upload" t:id="files" t:value="files" t:validate="required"/>
    <input t:type="upload" t:id="files" t:value="files" t:validate="required"/>
</t:form>
```

Sample.java

```java
@Property
private UploadedFile[] files;
```

This trick doesn't work. Can I do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to loop over a pre-instantiated array of `UploadedFile`s:

```java
@Property
private UploadedFile[] files = new UploadedFile[4];

@Property
private File currentFile;
```

Template:

```html
<t:form>
    <t:Loop t:source="files" t:value="currentFile">
        <input t:type="upload" t:id="files" t:value="currentFile" />
    </t:Loop>
    ...
<t:form>
```

I haven't tried this out, though.

Comment: This works, the only thing I've to rename is t:value="currentFile". Thx =)

Comment: @itsme: Right, sorry. I've corrected it in my answer as well.